# how to define create_tf_dataset_from_all_clients() function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-federated

I am trying to make a centralized dataset from a federated one. Data contains path, client_id and label

So first I create a clientdata object using a function that accepts the client's id

```
def extract_file_paths(dataset):
  return [item["path"] for item in dataset]

@tf.function
def create_dataset(client_id):
    new_datset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(df_aml))
    client_id = int(client_id)
    client_id = tf.cast(client_id, dtype=tf.int64)

    files = new_datset.filter(lambda x: x['client_id'] == client_id)


    list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(tf.py_function(func=extract_file_paths,inp=[files], Tout = tf.string ))
    
    
    images_ds = list_ds.map(parse_image)

        
    return images_ds
```

creating clientdata:

```
client_ids = ['0', '1', '2']


client_data = tff.simulation.datasets.ClientData.from_clients_and_tf_fn(client_ids,
create_dataset)

centralized = client_data.create_tf_dataset_from_all_clients()
```

I expected a dataset with different labels and files but this code is producing a dataset with only one file in it. Is it because I am trying to implement the graph execution method?

I tried using a similar function for creating a clientdata object that works for federated settings and produces the expected dataset, but using the same function gives me an error when I try to produce a centralized dataset

Comment: Could the question be extended to include the definition of `extract_file_paths`?

Comment: @ZacharyGarrett, It's already included before create_dataset, but here it is def extract_file_paths(dataset):
  return [item["path"] for item in dataset]